# ¿Para que sirve realizar los simbolos | y >>> dentro de un System.out.println()?

Tags: java, java-swing, spring

No entiendo el propósito de usar esto y muchisimo menos de lo que hacen:

```
System.out.println( -1 >>> 2); 
System.out.println( 2 >> 1);
```

imprime una cantidad de números pero no se realmente lo que hacen.

Ahora:

```
System.out.println(4|3);
```

Da apariencia de sumar los dos numeros y a su vez mostarlos en pantalla, pero, cuando probé con esto:

```
System.out.println(50|10);
```

Imprime como resultado *58*. Por lo que realmente no suma.

También me gustaría saber como se llaman este tipo de operaciones raras, ya que no encuentro como relacionarlo con otra cosa.

Comment: Te recomiendo esta publicación de SO en inglés es una duda similar a la tuya https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921145/what-does-do-in-java

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Investigaste algo sobre esto? lo buscaste en un buscador?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Son operaciones a nivel de bits.
Por ejemplo, el caso de 50|10:

```
50--> 00110010
10--> 00001010
     -----------
58--> 00111010
```

Si vamos haciendo la operación "OR" (|) bit a bit, el resultado es 58 (00111010 en binario)

En el caso de 4|3, el resultado coincide con la suma, pero lo que está haciendo es un "OR" de los bits correspondientes.

El operador >> ó << son desplazamientos de bits a derecha y a izquierda respectivamente.
Por ejemplo:

```
0110>>1 = 0011 (desplazamos un bit a la derecha)
```

El operador >>> ó <<< es lo mismo pero sin tener en cuenta el signo